# Unable to delete the data from mysql table which is fetched from a form in HTML using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-mysql

I am want to: 
1. save data from a HTML form to MySQL
2. delete data from mySQL which is entered through HTML form.

The save functionality is working. While there is error in delete functionality.

Model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class info_needed(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import info_needed

def index(request):
    return render(request,'userdata/index.html')

def message(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fname = request.POST.get("fname")
        lname = request.POST.get("lname")
        mail = request.POST.get("mail")
        action = request.POST.get("submit_button")
        action1 = request.POST.get("delete_button")
        p = info_needed(name = fname , surname = lname, email = mail)
        print("name", fname)
        print("action", action)
        print("action2", action1)
        if action == "Submit":
            p.save()
        elif action1 == "Delete":

            p.delete()
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Wrong Action Provided")

    return(HttpResponse("Thank you for submitting your details"))
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('submit/', views.message, name = 'submit'),
]
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="{% url 'submit' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
  <label for="fname">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Surname:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <label for="mail">E-Mail:</label>
  <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail"><br><br>
    <label for="submit_button">Save</label>
    <input type="radio"  name="submit_button" id="submit_button" value="Submit">
    <label for="delete_button">Delete</label>
  <input type="radio" name="delete_button" id="delete_button" value="Delete">
    <input type="submit", value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Error while deleting:

```
AssertionError at /userdata/submit/
info_needed object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None.
```

The primary id is automoatically genenrated, how to delete the row entry in mysql where the name, surname, and email matches?

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line

```
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

you don't need it ... django  will make it automatically

-- UPDATE

OK, i get this
you shouldn't make id like this `<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>`

So i suggest to follow the docs here : [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) then 
make this code into your form and it will work

```
class DeletableModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Model form that allows you to delete the object
    """
    delete = forms.BooleanField(
        initial=False,
        help_text=_('Check this to delete this object')
    )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if self.cleaned_data['delete']:
            return self.instance.delete()
        return super(DeletableModelForm, self).save()
```

Comment: I added that later on to check if something changes. The delete functionality does not work even after removing the line.